# What conditions will cause an iOS app to be shut down by the OS besides high memory usage?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, remoteio

I am having a frustrating stability problem with an iPad app.  On iPad 2, the app runs fine with no crashes, but on iPad 1, it will shut down randomly in the same way that it shuts down when memory usage is too high (the app stops running on the device, the debugger changes to "Paused" state, and the console window says "(gdb)").  However, memory allocations are below 5MB, so I'm clueless as to what I should do to keep the OS from shutting me down.

My app runs in real time with OpenGLES and the RemoteIO audio unit.  So it's constantly processing, but the crashes do not occur during heavy use cases.

Also the app is much more stable when not run in the debugger.

Does iOS shut down apps for any reason besides high memory usage?  And how would I debug what those reasons are so that I can fix them?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm finding that the crashes appear to be related to the number of vertices that I'm graphing with `GL_LINE_STRIP`.  I have multiple objects on the screen, each consisting of a single line strip with 2500 vertices.  Once I have ~8 objects (~20,000 total vertices), the stability becomes dodgy.

Also, I am alpha blending the line strips.

Any way to fix this without just dropping my resolution?

Comment: You are getting dumped into the debugger.  Do you get any errors?  What does a backtrace (`bt`) show?  Unlikely as it sounds, is it possible that you set a breakpoint that is being triggered?

Comment: There are no errors shown in the console (a.k.a. the "Log").  There is no backtrace given.  If you click the dropdown arrow in the Debug navigator next to the app name, nothing appears below it.  I have checked breakpoints, and there are none being triggered.  Annoying, huh?

Comment: Wait, you're saying that if you run `bt` in the console (it's really a debugger console that happens to also show the log) that nothing happens?

Comment: Wow, never realized that it was actually a debugger console :P  `bt` returns `No stack.`

Comment: Are your iPads running different iOS versions?

Comment: The iPad 1 is running iOS 5.1, while the iPad 2 is running 4.3.  However, I'm pretty sure that this problem existed before upgrading the iPad 1 from 4.3.  I could upgrade the iPad 2, but I would like to keep 4.3 for testing...

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found involved two parts:

1) I was displaying some UIKit views on top of the OpenGLES view from time to time.  Whenever these views were displayed, stopping all OpenGLES rendering calls helped to stabilize.

2) Calling `glFinish()` for every few calls to `glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, ... )` also helped to stabilize.

Changing alpha for the lines strips to 1 had no effect.

**BOTTOM LINE**:  Your app can crash with no stack trace or errors when there are (presumably hardware) issues with OpenGLES.

My guess is that the combination of UIKit views with an OpenGLES view, or glDrawArrays calls with large numbers of indices can overload the graphics "buffers" (see last paragraphs here: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_overview.html#flush)